# Custom screen resolutions with Intel graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, display, resolution, intel-graphics

I plugged in an old monitor as an extra screen and noticed that the picture did not cover the full screen without stretching.

I have an Intel Graphics Card with the native drivers installed. When I tried to select the option "Custom Resolutions" I got this rather scary warning threatening extensive damage to my computer:

[image: error]

What does it mean? What will happen if I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

This is a just a warning should you enter parameters that would cause the graphics chip to overheat or otherwise cause problems with the system. Myself I have used the customs resolutions option to set resolutions that weren't offered as a choice otherwise. I haven't used them to push the limits so I haven't had any issues and this is in an enterprise setting. Typically I see the older hardware not supporting the newer standards (Widescreen). I've used 1280 x 800 @ 72Hz 32 bit colour or 1440 x 900 @60hz 32bit colour as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) Look at the monitor and see if there are settings that you can adjust for the horizontal and vertical size.

2) Your LCD on your laptop ( I'm assuming it's a laptop ) is probably running at a vertical scan rate of 60 HZ which may be a scan rate that is too low for the old monitor to fill the screen.  Try reducing your resolution on your main LCD monitor and see if the monitors image increases in size.

Comment: 1) Adjusting the monitor's horizontal and vertical size with the physical buttons on the monitor stretches the picture.
2) It is running at 60 HZ but it doesn't go any higher.